# how to return value in read-only indexer without explicitly defining array

Tags: c#

i want to create an indexer that is read-only indexer. that provide a class with any an array type property but i did not know how to return values for the get accessor  to the loop the main body here is code that i want to compiler for that purpose

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace ConsoleApplication5
    {
        class arrys {


            public int this[int index]
            {
                //get accessor 
                get
                {
                    if (index >= 0 && index < 16)
                       //how i can return value from here
                    else
                        return -1;
                }
                //set accessor 
               /* set
                {

                }*/


            }


            }




        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                arrys a1 = new arrys();
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
                    {
                        int a = a1[i];
                        Console.WriteLine("a:" + a);

                    }

                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: "how i can return value from here". First put any value on your class then you'll know how to return it.

Comment: What will the value be, you want to return? Either you must have some data to gather your return value from (collection, other class, whatsoever, ...) or you will have to define a function f(i) which calculates your return value.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a collection, so you can return something.

For example:

```
class arrys {
  int[] _values;

  public arrys(int size)
  {
       _values = new int[size];
  }

  public int this[int index]
  {
      if (index < _values.Length)
            _values[index];
      else
           return -1;
  }
}

// Usage

arrys a1 = new arrys(21);
for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
{
     int a = a1[i];
     Console.WriteLine("a:" + a);
}
```

Ofcourse this will write just zeros to the console because you didn't set the values.

Answer (score -3):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class arrys {


        public int this[int index]
        {
            //get accessor 
            get
            {
                if (index >= 0 && index < 16)
                   return index;
                else
                    return -1;
            }
            //set accessor 
           /* set
            {

            }*/


        }


        }




    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            arrys a1 = new arrys();
                for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
                {
                    int a = a1[i];
                    Console.WriteLine("a:" + a);

                }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```